# Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks on the second dropdown link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar with multiple drop downs. So when I click on the first link it opens the drop down, but when I click on the second link, the first drop down doesn't close. (so I want to close the drop down menu if the user clicks on second link)

```js
// main.js (javascript file)

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav1");
  if (x.className === "topnav1") {
    x.className += " responsive1";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav1";
  }
}

function toggleDropDown(myid) {
  var element = document.getElementById(myid);
  element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn1')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content1");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('mystyle')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('mystyle');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* style.css (css file - css is all correct if anything you think is not added i only need help with javascript) */

.topnav1 {
  background-color: blue !important;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav1 a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FDFDFD;
}

.topnav-right1 {
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .topnav-right1 {
    float: left;
  }
}

.para-active {
  background-color: #4F7ADA !important;
  color: black !important;
}

.para-active button {
  color: white !important;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */

.active1 {
  color: black !important;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

.topnav1 .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown1 {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
}

/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */

.dropdown1 .dropbtn1 {
  font-size: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FDFDFD;
}

/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */

.dropdown-content1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 96px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.mystyle {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav1" id="myTopnav1">
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <button style="display: none;" id="btn_em" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_em')" class="dropbtn1">Meters 
                </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_em">
      <label class="dropnav-container">one</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">one</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">one</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <button id="btn_inv" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_inv')" class="dropbtn1">Inverters 
                </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_inv">
      <label class="dropnav-container">two</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">two</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">two</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <button id="btn_inm" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_inm')" class="dropbtn1">Inverter Manager 
                </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_inm">
      <label class="dropnav-container">three</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">three</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">three</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <button id="btn_ws" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_ws')" class="dropbtn1">Sensors 
                </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_ws">
      <label class="dropnav-container">four</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">four</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">four</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <button id="btn_smu" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_smu')" class="dropbtn1">SMUs 
                </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_smu">
      <label class="dropnav-container">five</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">five</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">five</label> </div>
  </div>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do the functionality with JavaScript, you have to use ids in order to close the other dropdowns, once a new one is open.

So, the solution I've worked on is creating a new method `closeMenus`, which will close the other dropdowns once you execute `toggleDropDown`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav1");
  if (x.className === "topnav1") {
    x.className += " responsive1";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav1";
  }
}

function toggleDropDown(myid) {
  closeMenus(myid);
  var element = document.getElementById(myid);
  element.classList.toggle("mystyle");  
}

function closeMenus(currentId) {
  var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content1");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('mystyle') && openDropdown.id !== currentId) {
      openDropdown.classList.remove('mystyle');
    }
  }
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn1')) {
    closeMenus();
  }
}
```

```css
.topnav1 {
  background-color: blue !important;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav1 a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FDFDFD;
}

.topnav-right1 {
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .topnav-right1 {
    float: left;
  }
}

.para-active {
  background-color: #4F7ADA !important;
  color: black !important;
}

.para-active button {
  color: white !important;
}


/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */

.active1 {
  color: black !important;
}


/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

.topnav1 .icon {
  display: none;
}


/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown1 {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
}


/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */

.dropdown1 .dropbtn1 {
  font-size: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FDFDFD;
}


/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */

.dropdown-content1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 96px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.mystyle {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav1" id="myTopnav1">
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <button style="display: none;" id="btn_em" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_em')" class="dropbtn1">Meters 
            </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_em">
      <label class="dropnav-container">one</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">one</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">one</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <button id="btn_inv" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_inv')" class="dropbtn1">Inverters 
            </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_inv">
      <label class="dropnav-container">two</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">two</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">two</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <button id="btn_inm" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_inm')" class="dropbtn1">Inverter Manager 
            </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_inm">
      <label class="dropnav-container">three</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">three</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">three</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <button id="btn_ws" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_ws')" class="dropbtn1">Sensors 
            </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_ws">
      <label class="dropnav-container">four</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">four</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">four</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <button id="btn_smu" onclick="toggleDropDown('div_smu')" class="dropbtn1">SMUs 
            </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content1" id="div_smu">
      <label class="dropnav-container">five</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">five</label>
      <label class="dropnav-container">five</label> </div>
  </div>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: yes , this works . I have one more problem , i have to apply active class to both nav link and the option selected from the dropdown. plzz help me with this one.

Comment: @lalitkumar sorry for the late response, you can add the active class when the user clicks on the element, you can see an example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp)

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your mystyle class makes the dropdown active.
Then you can do something like this

```
// Get all the dropdowns
var dropdowns = document.getElementByClassName(".dropdown1")

// When clicked on dropdown this function will fire
var callThisFunction = function (e) {
    // Check the event
    e = e || window.event;

    // Get the target element
    let target = e.target || e.srcElement;

    // Close all dropdowns
    let activeDropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("mystyle");
    activeDropdowns.forEach(function (openDropdown) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('mystyle');
    })

    // Make the current dropdown active
    target.className += 'mystyle'
}

// This adds click event listener to all dropdowns and tells it to fire callThisFunction when clicked

dropdowns.forEach(function (dropdown) {
    dropdown[i].addEventListener('click', callThisFunction, false);
})
```

Comment: I have one more problem , i have to apply active class to both nav link and the option selected from the dropdown. plzz help me with this one.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use **JQUERY** *(CDN BELOW)*

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js

Jquery is super fast and helpful
because your problem will be solved like this in jquery.

```
$('.yourdropdownsclass').on('click', function(){
   var target = $(this).attr('id');
   $("#"+target).show().siblings("div").hide();
});
```

> .yourdropdownclass

is class of your dropdowns

> $(this).attr('id')

this is getting the ids of another dropdowns.

> $("#"+target).show().siblings("div").hide();

"target" is the name of ids of other dropdowns and storing it to variable and showing it and hiding another sibling's dropdowns.
**I hope it will help you!**

Comment: “this is getting the ids of another dropdowns”. That line gets the id of the drop down you clicked (which assumes there is an ID at all), and then you proceed to look it up using `$("#"+target)`, which is exactly the same element as `$(this)`. “Target is the name of ids of other dropdowns”, no it’s not. This code shows the element you clicked (in a roundabout and potentially invalid way because it assumes you have an id) and then hides the sibling divs of the element you clicked. Reminder: IDs must be unique.

Comment: It means your problem is solved or not. yet. Yes sorry, my mistake but Are siblings hiding?.

Comment: I’m not the OP, but `$(this).show().siblings("div").hide();` does the same thing as the 2 lines you have, but is safer because it doesn’t assume any IDs. Whether it works or not, I’m unsure. But it accomplishes the same thing.